# Virtual model in PLC discrete / continuous

Tags: control

How does one implement virtual model (continuous) while control system itself is discrete (PLC)?

I've done this in practice but what about theory, how does one explain this topic to a stranger? (lets say myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to discretize the model. This is typically done with a [z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform), where

$$
z = e^{sT}
$$
or
$$
s \approx \frac{2}{T} \frac{z-1}{z+1}
$$

where $T$ is the sample period. Make the substitution in your CT model, replacing $s$ with the above, then solve it like you would for an ordinary transfer function.

Once you've done this, divide everything by the highest order of $z$ in the transfer function. Now $z^{-n}$ represents a delay of $n$ samples, so:

$$
Y(z) = X(z) + X(z) z^{-1}
$$

becomes
$$
Y_n = X_n + X_{n-1}
$$

This is very much akin to the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), where you get functions of $s$, where $\frac{1}{s}$ is the integrator and $s$ is the differentiator. Here $z^n$ represents $n$ samples in the future where $z^{-n}$ represents $n$ samples in the past; this is why you must divide by the highest order of z - you can't get future samples.

$$
Y(s) = X(s) + sX(s)
$$
becomes
$$
y = x + \dot{x}
$$
So, regarding how to explain to someone **how** to implement a continuous model on a discrete controller, this is it. The Z-transform. **Why** this works the subject of many text books and much too long of an answer to cover here.